# install RStudio on Ubuntu 18.04 - 32 bit

Tags: rstudio

I use Ubuntu 18.04 - 32 bit. Is it possible for me to install RStudio?

I have tried to install older versions of RStudio from [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio) (RStudio Desktop 0.97.551 or RStudio Desktop 0.96.331). But they didn't work (I mean files have installed, no warnings, I can see the icon of RStudio, but it doesn't start at all)

Comment: You may have got more useful information if you actually said why they didn't work; ie. the site you linked offers debs, so was it issues installing, issues with dependencies, or no issues installing but it was during execution where you couldn't understand the crash reports?

Comment: @guiverc, thanks, done. I really don't know what to add...

Comment: From the deb file you can see what files were installed and guess the executable (from location it was installed to I bet), so when executed from terminal did you get any messages?

Comment: @guiverc  actually yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the following method on 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-0.97.551-i386.deb
sudo apt install ./rstudio-0.97.551-i386.deb
rstudio
```

It really does not start and shows the following error message:

```
$ rstudio 
rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and the mentioned file [was available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=i386&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgstapp-0.10.so.0) only for previous Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

So we need to install it manually by downloading two packages:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gstreamer0.10/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1_i386.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gst-plugins-base0.10/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2ubuntu0.2_i386.deb
sudo apt install ./libgstreamer*.deb
```

And then it will complain about missed libpng12. I suppose that it is a bad idea to install it manually.

But we can use newer version of RStudio as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.1.463-i386.deb
sudo apt install ./rstudio-1.1.463-i386.deb
```

and use it without problems:

[image: RStudio 32-bit]